# Windows 8 RDP autologout for specific user after n minutes idle

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop

I require an autologout on my RDP Session for only my user after n minutes idle time.

Is there a program or a setting to achieve this only for my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GPO for this: "Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions" (more details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791886%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

It is a user policy so you can configure it to be only valid for a specific user. As stated in the linked article it would only disconnect you not log you out. To also log you out you would need to configure the Computer policy "Terminate session when time limits are reached". This would affect all users but as long as you don't specify any limits for them it would never become relevant.

If you don't have access to GPOs on this computer you can manually create

a dword named `MaxIdleTime` under

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
```

which should imo specify the time in milliseconds.

The other setting is a dword `fResetBroken` in

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\

with value 1.
During my research for this I found some articles indicating that the second setting could also be created in the HKCU hive, which would impact other users even less. The placement of the policy would not really hint to this being possible but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `task scheduler` to create task that trigger on system Idle as described  [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d358382c-e91b-4e91-a1e8-04c53cfd91ce/automatic-logout-after-inactivityidle) with action `shutdown.exe /l` . A scheduled task named set to run when the user logs on or when the system goes idle, and with Conditions set to run only if idle for 30 minutes.  It's set to run only when user is logged on